# Feyncalc Chain re-ordering problem

Tags: feyncalc

I am encountering a similar problem with much more complex terms than the ones shown in the figures below. Basically, I wrote the chain for a process(in this case, a simple 2 particle scattering in QED).

We add 2 same order processes which vary only in the interchange of final fermions (as shown in expressions $M_1$ and $M_2$ respectively). On performing the $\textit{FermionSpinSum}$ on $M = M_1+M_2$, we can see that there are spinors in the answers, which leads me to conclude that somehow the re-ordering of the spinor indices have not taken place.

```
M1=(-e^3 /SP[q2])*(Spinor[p3, m2].GA[μ].Spinor[-p4,m2]).MT[μ, δ].(Spinor[p2, m2].GA[δ].Spinor[p1,m2]);

M2= (-e^3 /SP[q2]) (Spinor[p3, m2].GA[μ].Spinor[-p4,m2]).MT[μ, δ].(Spinor[-p1, m2].GA[δ].Spinor[p2,
  m2]);

M = M1 + M2;

FermionSpinSum[ComplexConjugate[M] M]
```

The output is,
[image]

Is this correct? Can someone point out any corrections please? I am facing a similar problem with a much more complicated second term, but I believe this is the crux of the issue.

Comment: At a minimum provide your code as text, not pictures.

Comment: Sorry @MarcoB. I've added the code as best as I could format it. I don't know why the Greek notations are not rendering here. There is no problem in running the same in a notebook.

Comment: I fixed them. I use [Halirutan's plugin for the M.SE editor](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1043/27951) to change the pasted encoded characters into actual Greek letters, as well as to add links to the documentation. It's great! I also use [this handy online converter at http://steampiano.net/msc/](http://steampiano.net/msc/) when I am on mobile.

Comment: What process exactly are you looking at?

Comment: This looks like Bhabha scattering, cf. e.g. (https://feyncalc.github.io/FeynCalcExamplesMD/QED/Tree/ElAel-ElAel) but the spinor chains look weird, and it is not really clear what reaction you are trying to calculate. Can you write the amplitude in LaTeX in your question?
BTW, there is an example gallery that contains most common simple tree-level QED processes: https://feyncalc.github.io/examples

Comment: Hmm, it seems that the OP has either figured out the issue by himself/herself or is not interested in the question anymore...

Comment: @vsht, I am sorry to have not replied sooner. I had some net connectivity issues until today morning. As such your last comment helped me out. I rewrote the code to extract the relevant amplitudes from the diagrams I wanted, symbolically as shown in the link provided. Thanks for the help. I guess I was indeed messing up the order of the spinor chain components.

Comment: @Lelouch No problem. Good to know that it's now resolved.